# private interface, public child and public factory that can only instantiate members within its namespace that inherit from private interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I was tinkering around with some code and out of curiosity I wanted to know how I can tackle this problem should I ever stumble upon it.

The problem is that I want to have an Interface and a generic (Factory) class that can only create objects that inherit from that interface. There exists concrete classes which implement that interface which are intended to be used by the generic factory; however, I do not want anyone to add to create their own implementations of the interface but I do want them to be able to create their own instances of the objects which inherit from that interface.

I have a piece of code which illustrates what I am trying to do; however, it does not compile because of the inconsistent accessibility. Here is a piece of code which illustrates what I am inquiring about

```
using System;
using InterfaceTest.Objects;
namespace InterfaceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreatureFactory<Person> p = new CreatureFactory<Person>();
            p.Create();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace InterfaceTest.Objects
{
    interface LivingCreature
    {
        int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person : LivingCreature
    {
        public int Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class CreatureFactory<T> where T : class, LivingCreature, new()
    {
        public T Create()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to prevent someone from deriving from `LivingCreature`? I don't think thats possible in C#, what would be different between the "valid" ones and the "invalid" ones?

Comment: I was thinking that the living creature could be an abstract class with partially working things; however, the interface seemed better for the sake of explanation.

Comment: Um what does *I do not want anyone to add to create their own implementations of the interface but I do want them to be able to create their own instances of the objects which inherit from that interface* mean?  It appears to be a broken sentence of a good train of thought.

Comment: If you dont want anyone to create a concrete type implementing vyour interface, then why create that interface?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov internal best practices to organize the team?

Comment: So that, other classes within the second namespace would be able to expect the class to have some logic.

Comment: Even with the abstract class, what makes a derivation "valid"? How would the compiler know who wrote it? You can seal classes of course, but then *no one* can derive. I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, or it is impossible if I do understand correctly.

Comment: @Admiral It looks like the interface is a contract for people to use rather than a "internal best practice"

Comment: Preventing somebody to inherit something by namespace does not work, because i can **always** use your namespace in my source files.

Comment: @elgonzo I did not know that was possible!

Comment: @Aelphaeis why dont you want anyone implementing that interface?

Comment: @elgonzo, @Aelphaeis, `internal` is about the *assembly*, not the namespace.

Comment: What you seem to look for is an `public` abstract class with an `internal` constructor. That means, only classes in the same assembly could derive and instantiate from that abstract class.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, yes i know it is about assembly. (I just edited my comment). Not sure whether the O/P is aiming for something like that or not...

Comment: I was thinking that if you had some resource external from the program that you wanted to managed within the assembly and the entire point to having a class is to represent something from that resource and the abstract class and the abstract class handled the the management of the unmanaged resource. The class itself can actually be made and used without access the unmanaged resource because you can give it all the values for other operations; however, if you do get it from the unmanaged resource the factory would do the work of getting it for you and we knew the types are finite.

Comment: @Aelphaeis, your last comments sounds like your issue is not about whether somebody should be allowed to inherit an interface. Do i understand you correctly, that you look for something like a (non-abstract) `sealed` class?

Comment: Well think about it like a video game. You have a file type in the video game such as a model. If you want to get the model from an existing file and you don't want the model editted while you're using it; however, you may also want to make a model from scratch; however, the types of models that you may want to make are very finite. You may find yourself in a similar situation and I'm thinking about the best way to handle such a situation.

Comment: I am afraid i do not understand what you try to explain here in the comments. I would suggest to look at the `internal` modifier (for creating a public abstract base class with *internal* constructor - preventing inheriting this class from types outside of the assembly providing this class) and the `sealed` modifier to prevent inheritance of a (concrete) class. (Note that an abstract base class is not the same as an interface, thus i am not sure if using an abstract base class is a feasible option in your scenario)

Comment: add public to your interface definition...

Comment: I probably explained it poorly. Lets say I got a compressed .avi file. I want to edit this file; however, I can create an avi file; however, if I choose to use an existing file and may want to edit something in real time. I may also want other programs to access it while I'm editing it (which is a very real scenario while modding). I want people to be able to make their own avi which is totally uncompressed and can be used normally; however, I don't want them making something that implements a compressed resource because the compressed resource implementation is very finite.

Comment: No. Stop explaining something that is not really related to your question (as it seems). Your question was about an interface (which implements some public members, obviously). Users of your code should be able to handle that interface (i.e., call its public methods) -- but they should be unable to create their own classes based on that interface. Correct? If not, please make your question more clear, but do not try to explain it in complex metaphors (as this would be subject to a lot of different interpretations)...

Comment: Yea, basically they should not really know the interface exists. They should only be concerned about the concrete implementation; however, the factory should only be able to instantiate valid objects which the programmer would deem valid by whatever means they choose

Comment: Then, what is the interface good for if users should not really know the interface? After all that would mean the users then would also not know and not be able to access any public members implemented by that interface, thus making the interface as desired by you more or less completely redundant/disfunctional -- or what would be the purpose of the interface then?

Comment: You could of course declare such an interface `internal` and having some public members in that interface. However, those members are essentially restricted by the interface's `internal` modifier and thus not accessible and not implementable outside of the assembly providing this interface. This in turn will still allow users of your assembly to derive from your concrete public classes (which implement this internal interface), however, for the users any interface member is simply not accessible... (not sure if that is what you actually want)

Comment: Well its most of the way there; however, its certainly a worth while thought. Put this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Ahh, dammit. I think i made a mistake when saying that public members of internal interfaces are internal too. Well, that was bullocks. In truth, the public members declared by an internal interface remain public and are thus be generally accessible. However, the internal interface itself is not being accessible outside its assembly... Sorry for talking nonsense there...